# doubt in using Location Listener

Tags: android, gps

I have used LastKnownLoaction at the start-up Activity of my app to get the location ,if it returns null then  i register for a  Location Listener for both gps and network providers.After requesting for Listener to listen for any location change i switch over to main Activity page using startActivity.Further in the startup Actyivity's onLocation in both Listener i am trying to get location and if any values found then i try to store them in preference and remove updated from both listener   and notify the user about the location being updated.

Is this logic is correct way of coding ,do the listener listen for location update when its no longer on the top of the stack ,hence i am using a emulator i couldn't test gps functionality,i required your suggestions on this
thanks

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't register a LocationListener only if getLastKnownLocation() returns null, because that means the particular location provider is disabled. Also caching a real-time value like location doesn't sound like a good design. I would suggest to register/unregister LocationListener for each Activity in it's onStart/onStop methods.